# how to find zkroot and clientid for SpoutConfig

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I'm tryingto connect to a remote kafka cluster in storm. I'm using the following code:

```
    Broker brokerForPartition0 = new Broker("208.113.164.114:9091");
            Broker brokerForPartition1 = new Broker("208.113.164.115:9092");
            Broker brokerForPartition2 = new Broker("208.113.164.117:9093");
            GlobalPartitionInformation partitionInfo = new GlobalPartitionInformation();
            partitionInfo.addPartition(0, brokerForPartition2);//mapping from partition 0 to brokerForPartition0
    partitionInfo.addPartition(1, brokerForPartition0);//mapping from partition 1 to brokerForPartition1
    partitionInfo.addPartition(2, brokerForPartition1);//mapping from partition 2 to brokerForPartition2
    StaticHosts hosts = new StaticHosts(partitionInfo);
    SpoutConfig spoutConfig = new SpoutConfig(hosts, "newImageTest","/brokers","console-consumer-61818");
    spoutConfig.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());
    KafkaSpout kafkaSpout = new KafkaSpout(spoutConfig);
```

In the instanciation of spoutConfig, I have to put as a parameters the zkroot and clientid.

```
    java public SpoutConfig(BrokerHosts hosts, String topic, String zkRoot, String id);
```

Where can I find these two information? Or should I create them?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From [this documentation](http://storm.apache.org/releases/0.10.0/storm-kafka.html),

> Spoutconfig is an extension of KafkaConfig that supports additional
>   fields with ZooKeeper connection info and for controlling behavior
>   specific to KafkaSpout. The Zkroot will be used as root to store your
>   consumer's offset. The id should uniquely identify your spout.

`Zkroot`, therefore should be some ZNode path like `/some/path` which will be used to store your consumer's offset as mentioned.

`id` is some string, (say a UUID) which can be used to uniquely identify your spout as mentioned.